# how can i execute python script via terminal in Java

Tags: java, python, macos, terminal

Im trying to run python script via terminal but it always throws an exception: **No such file or directory**

```
StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

String command = "python3 Users/lounah/Documents/programming/ApplicationName/scriptName.py " + params.toString();

ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
Process process = processBuilder.start();

BufferedReader reader =
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
    output.append(line + "\n");
}
```

Comment: Does the file/directory exist?

Comment: @hyperneutrino yes

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a string in `ProcessBuilder` it tries to run a program located in that path.
Instaed you should use a `String[]`  with the path of your executable (  `'/python3/python.exe'` or `'python'` or `'py'`) followed by  the path of your script, followed by the arguments.

```
String[] command = {
    "python3",
    "Users/lounah/Documents/programming/ApplicationName/scriptName.py", 
    params.toString()
};
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
```